# Optimize a point to a hyperbola

Tags: calculus, optimization, hyperbolic-functions

Question: Find the location of the points on $y=\frac 1x$ that are closest to the point $(-1,1)$.

Attempted answer:
$f(x)=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+\left(\frac 1x-1\right)^2}$

taking the derivative of the function inside the square root gets me:
$2(x+1)+(2\left(x^{-1}-1\right))\left(-x^{-2}\right)$

simplifying this gets me to:
$2x+2-2x^{-3}+2x^{-2}$

so:
$2(x+1-x^{-3}+x^{-2})=0$

I end up getting to:
$x-x^{-3}+x^{-2}=-1$

I have no idea what to do at this point, although I feel like I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong to begin with.
I know the answer is supposed to end up at $(-1.6180,-0.6180),(0.6180,-1.680)$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Multiply through by $x^3$ to get $x^4+x^3-1+x=0$. You can write the LHS as $x^4-1+x(x^2+1)=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)+x(x^2+1)=(x^2+1)(x^2+x-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation (simplified) can be factorized as $$2\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+x-1 \right) =0$$